# Connectivity of infinite product space

Tags: general-topology

In **James.E.Munkres** there is a theorem that says **A finite cartesian product of connected space is connected**. But what about infinite product spaces? Though there are few more question like this in the site some of them consider path connected or many other theorems that I don't understand. So if you can give a simple example that will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Oh. OK.  Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257981/4280 has a proof sketch (with some details filled in in its answer) of the arbitrary product case.